# Spring Integration Java DSL: How to route the flow to the error channel if there occurs an error

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

How to route the flow from the channel `myChannel` to the error channel `myErrorChannel` if there occurs an error in the `Http.outboundGateway` call?

```
@Bean
private IntegrationFlow myChannel() {
    return f -> f
            .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/greeting")
                    ...
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class));
}

@Bean
private IntegrationFlow myErrorChannel() {
    return f -> f
            ...
}
```

In the error handler I will wrap the error message inside my custom JSON and I will send that as a part of the normal flow back to the source system.

Is this a good way to handle errors in the Spring Integration Java DSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` with its `returnFailureExpressionResult = true` and use it in the second argument of the `.handle(..., e -> e.advice(...))`.

You configure that advice for the `onFailureExpression` to be able to return something meaningful. If you still think that you need to send to the channel and get reply back, then you need to have a `@MessagingGateway` and use it in that `onFailureExpression` to send and receive. The normal `failureChannel` configuration in the  `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` doesn't expect reply.

Another approach can be done using the same `@MessagingGateway`, but in front of that `myChannel` `IntegrationFlow`. Then you can configure that gateway for the `errorChannel` and here a reply from the error flow is expected.